# Server, get data from a ethereum smart contract

Tags: javascript, ethereum

I have a server where a javascript application runs. Now a user can get access to a smart contract via web3 to get data from it. Since only writing to the contract and not reading is critical, I want the read out of the data buffered from the server, but I actually don't know what the best approach would be. Should I use php and mysql to achieve this?